# Scroll in horizontal way in html table

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, jquery

i have this Html code : [code](http://pastebin.com/zJqemFM5)

it is a html table with the possibilities of vertical and horizontal scrolling.

i need only the vertical scrolling ie make the width of the table fixe and scroll vertically.

So how can i change my snippet to get this result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On line 55 of your pastebin you have:

```
<div id="table_div" style="overflow: scroll;width:400px;height:200px;position:relative" " >
```

Change to:

```
<div id="table_div" style="overflow-y: scroll;width:400px;height:200px;position:relative" >
```

(Note that there is an extra " at the end of your original)

Then you just need to add a few more rows to table to see the scrolling. You were almost there!

http://jsfiddle.net/nWPzp/1/